# Can multiple cores simultaneously read the same RAM location?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Can multiple cores simultaneously read the same RAM location? I am interested in x86 architecture CPU's in particular. Also can the internal caches of two different cores on the same CPU get filled at the same time from the same RAM locations?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "at the same time" - there can only be one bus read cycle from DRAM at any given time, but cache snooping logic between cores will take care of cache coherence.

Comment: @Paul R: With "at the same time" I mean at time X, doing a load in both cores from address ADDR will load the value at ADDR in a register in both cores.

Comment: @Lyth give a good answer below, but the short answer is no: you can't load two cores from one address is one bus read cycle.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks. I believe there is a particular case when this can happen. If L1 caches have been filled with the same data from RAM, then a load in each of the cores in the same cycle will load a register with the same value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Only if both L1 lines are already in "shared" state (see MESI protocol in the mentioned article). And note, that the actual implementation is manufacturer-dependent, you'll never know how it is implemented in hardware nor trace the effects, except for some delays during cache state transitions.

Comment: @Copil: in your question you specifically stated "RAM location", but Lyth's comment is valid re caches etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, they can read independently and caches will be filled independently, though the location may be preloaded in shared L3 cache. Synchronisation is not guaranteed to the precise tick, but memory state is coherent and transparent to the application. There is an excellent article on memory by Ulrich Drepper, which is a must read: http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/

Comment: wow looks like a super comprehensive article indeed, definitely bookmarked it.